# How to convert Counter object to dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

Data frame:

```
pair = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
```

e.g.

```
pair = {'doc1':  {'word1':4, 'word2':3}, 
        'doc2':  {'word1':2, 'word3':4},
        'doc3':  {'word2':2, 'word4':1},
         ...}
```

I want to keep the data frame but alter the type of this part `{'word1':4, 'word2':3}` ``` {'word1':2, 'word3':4}``... ``` It is now a `Counter` and I need a `dict`.

I tried this to get the data from `pair`, but I do not know how to create a `dict` for each doc:

```
new_pair = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
for doc, tab in testing.form.items():
    for word, freq in tab.items():
        new_pair[doc][word] = freq
```

I do not want to change the output. I just need that **in each doc, the data type is `dict`, not `Counter`.**

Comment: Post the actual traceback and more context.

Comment: WHO says  'first argument must be callable' ?

Comment: what do you want? Can you give the output that you want?

Comment: @joaquin `collections.defaultdict` argument

Comment: it's this line `collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter())` why isn't it `collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)` which you did before?

Comment: @jamylak Yes. definitely my fault. But this fraction of code does not change the data type to `dict`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 103):

A `Counter` is already a `dict` - or, a subclass of it. But, if you really need exactly a `dict` for some reason, then its a one-liner:

```
>>> c = Counter(word1=4, word2=3)
>>> c
Counter({'word1': 4, 'word2': 3})
>>> dict(c)
{'word1': 4, 'word2': 3}
```

Any Mapping (anything that behaves like a dictionary) can be passed into `dict`, and you will get a `dict` with the same contents. There is no need to iterate over it to construct it yourself.

This gives you one loop, with one line in the body instead of a nested loop. But any code of the form:

```
 thing = a new empty collection
 for elem in old_thing:
    Add something to do with elem to thing
```

Can usually be done in one line using a generator expression or a list, set or dict comprehension. We're building a `dict`, so a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (the Examples section is what you're most interested in) seems likely. I'll leave coming up with it as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

Comment: +1 Since the functionality of a `Counter` is needed it can only be converted into `dict` after so this is the only way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

Since Counter is already a dict.
I would like to suggest this in addition to @lvc answer as well.

```
>>> c = Counter(word1=4, word2=3)
>>> c
Counter({'word1': 4, 'word2': 3})
>>> isinstance(c,dict)
True
>>> {**c}
{'word1': 4, 'word2': 3}
```

This allows you to add more key and combine multiple dict or counter

```
>>> {**c, 'total': sum(c.values())}
{'word1': 4, 'word2': 3, 'total': 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> pair = defaultdict(dict)
>>> pair[3][2]='hello'
>>>
>>> pair
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {3: {2: 'hello'}})
>>>
>>> pair[3]
{2: 'hello'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_pair = {} # simple dict at the top level
for doc, tab in testing.form.items():
    for word, freq in tab.items():
        # top-level values is word counters
        new_pair[doc].setdefault(word, Counter()) += freq
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Counter` is also a `dict`. But depend on you need, maybe the follow code is you want.

```
new_pair ={}
for doc, tab in pari.items():
    new_pair[doc] = {}
    for word, freq in tab.items():
        new_pair[doc][word] = freq
```

the `new_pair` dict is you want. Good Luck!