# Python: count the occurrences of each item from a lists of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm a newbie to coding. I need to count the number of occurrences of each item in a list of lists. Here is an example of the list of list I deal with:

```
GC = [[5,4,3,2,1],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[10,9,8,7,6,5,4]]
```

and print the results in two columns. column 1 = range of list of list elements, column 2 = total occurrences of each element.

Comment: what so you mean by range?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish that easily using some built-in libraries/modules:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

l = [[5,4,3,2,1],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[10,9,8,7,6,5,4]]

l = chain.from_iterable(l)

print Counter(l)
```

`chain.from_iterable(l)` flattens the list into 1 dimension and then the `Counter` constructor creates a Counter object which is basically dictionary mapping each unique item to its count in the list.

Comment: sshanshank, thanks for the answer. I get Counter({4: 4, 2: 3, 3: 3, 5: 3, 1: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 1}). How could I then organize the list to go from largest to smallest in sequence? ex: 10:1, 9:2, 8:2, 7:2...etc

Comment: @FuturesTrader, `dictionaries` cannot be ordered. Try getting the items into a list and then sorting the list.

Comment: @FuturesTrader `for k in sorted(keys(the_counts)): print k, the_counts[k]`

Comment: How can one make the ```Counter({blabla})``` disappear and only print out the dictionary though? Is there a function/way to that or should one manually do it?

Comment: @Liana https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068986/how-to-convert-counter-object-to-dict

Answer (score 1):

If you want each number and the count in columns:

```
l = [[5,4,3,2,1],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[10,9,8,7,6,5,4]]

flattened = ([x for y in l for x in y])
counts = [[ele,flattened.count(ele)]for ind, ele in enumerate(set(flattened))]
print counts 
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 2], [8, 2], [9, 2], [10, 1]]
```

Comment: Padraic, I tried some "real" data and things didn't seem to work the same way. Here is the data: l = [[1320.5,1320.4,1320.3,1320.2,1320.1],[1320.9,1320.8,1320.7,1320.6,1320.5,1320.4,1320.3,1320.2],[1320.4,1320.3,1320.2,1320.1],[1321.0,1320.9,1320.8,1320.7,1320.6,1320.5,1320.4]]

Comment: @FuturesTrader, it seems to work for me, what is not working for you?

Comment: l = [[1320.5,1320.4,1320.3,1320.2,1320.1],[1320.9,1320.8,1320.7,1320.6,1320.5,1320.4,1320.3,1320.2],[1320.4,1320.3,1320.2,1320.1],[1321.0,1320.9,1320.8,1320.7,1320.6,1320.5,1320.4]]
 
flattened = ([x for y in l for x in y])
counts = [[ele,flattened.count(ele)]for ind, ele in enumerate(set(flattened))]
print counts[[1320.5, 3], [1320.7, 2], [1320.4, 4], [1320.9, 2], [1320.8, 2], [1320.3, 3], [1320.2, 3], [1320.6, 2], [1320.1, 2], [1321.0, 1]]

Comment: this is the result I get for the above "real" data:
print counts[[1320.5, 3], [1320.7, 2], [1320.4, 4], [1320.9, 2], [1320.8, 2], [1320.3, 3], [1320.2, 3], [1320.6, 2], [1320.1, 2], [1321.0, 1]]      #in the original example, the data was correctly organized from low to high [lowest data value, occurrences of this value]. Using the "real" data, the data is out of sequence. The first "pair" of data should be [1320.1,2] this pair represents [lowest data value,# of occurrences of lowest data value].

Answer (score 0):

If your new to programming then maybe you are doing this to get an idea of how loops work, in that case the example below may help. But its important to note its not the most efficient method see sshashank124 or Padraic Cunningham answers above.

```
GC = [[5,4,3,2,1],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[10,9,8,7,6,5,4]]

nums = list(set(flatten(GC)))
occurances = []

for i in nums:        
    p = 0

    for i2 in GC:   
        for k2 in i2:  
            if i == k2:   
                p += 1   

    occurances.append(p)  # save total count in list
print zip(nums, occurances)
```