# How to combine dictionaries in a list into one dictionary with values of same keys added?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-lists

I am trying to convert a list that contains dictionaries to one dictionary where the values for common keys are added.

Use this list as an example:

```
list = [{'Apple': 3, 'Orange': 2}, {'Apple': 1, 'Grapes': 3, 'Orange': 1}, {'Apple': 2}]
```

I want a function that will take that list as an input and return the following as the output:

```
{'Apple': 6, 'Orange': 3, 'Grapes': 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter

fruit_dicts = [
    {'Apple': 3, 'Orange': 2},
    {'Apple': 1, 'Grapes': 3, 'Orange': 1},
    {'Apple': 2}
]

counter = Counter()
for fruit_dict in fruit_dicts:
    counter.update(fruit_dict)

print(counter)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'Apple': 6, 'Orange': 3, 'Grapes': 3})
```

**EDIT** Without using `collections.Counter`:

```
fruit_dicts = [
    {'Apple': 3, 'Orange': 2},
    {'Apple': 1, 'Grapes': 3, 'Orange': 1},
    {'Apple': 2}
]

counter = {}
for fruit_dict in fruit_dicts:
    for key, value in fruit_dict.items():
        counter.update({key: counter.get(key, 0) + value})

print(counter)
```

Comment: And if you want it to be a regular `dict` (and not a `Counter` subclass): `print(dict(counter))`.  See also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11069022/3399890).

Comment: Thank you for the response. We have not yet learned the collections module. Is there a way without using counter?

Comment: Thank you for the help.